# "DBpedia as Tables" not having all the properties

Tags: linked-data, wikipedia, csv

I browsed a sample for available data at http://dbpedia.org/page/Sachin_Tendulkar. I wanted these properties as columns, so I downloaded the CSV files from http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables.

Now, when I browse the data for the same entity "Sachin_Tendulkar", I find that many of the properties are not available (e.g. the property "dbpprop:bestBowling" is not present).

How can I get all the properties which I can see at the direct resource page of the entity?

Comment: Which CSV file(s) did you use? Was it [Cricketer.csv.gz](http://web.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/DBpediaAsTables/csv/Cricketer.csv.gz)?

Comment: This question has also been [answered on DataScience.SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/2521/5164)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [DBpedia as Tables](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables), DBpedia uses the following data to create the tables:

> Each instance is described by its URI, an English label and a short abstract, **the mapping-based infobox data describing the instance (extracted from the English edition of Wikipedia)**, geo-coordinates, and external links.

DBpedia basically provides two different types of data: the *Infobox Dataset* (everything beginning with *dbpprop*) and the *Mapping-based Dataset* (everything beginning with *dbpedia-owl*). If you're interested, you can [read more about the difference](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h434-10).

For these tables, only the mapping-based data (*dbpedia-owl:…*) is used. That's why you won't find any raw infobox properties starting with *dbprop* — however, you can [download the raw data](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2014#download-c14n-raw-infobox-properties) if you're really interested.

[Quick note from DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2014#raw-infobox-properties) about the raw infobox properties though:

> Information that has been extracted from Wikipedia infoboxes. Note that this data is in the less clean /property/ namespace. The Mapping-based Properties (/ontology/ namespace) should always be preferred over this data.